# Android Studio For loop on

Tags: android, arrays, loops, textview

I've been programming all day and my brain just can't get around to figuring a question to a problem.

I'm trying to loop through an `array` of user names and populate a `TextView` depending on the location in the array. I'm using an `adapter` to do this. The problem I'm running into is that when I set the text for userNameTextView, only the name for the last position in the for loop will be set for the `TextView`.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response){
            if(users != null){

                String[] names = new String[users.size()];
                for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
                    names[i] = users.get(i).getName();
                    mUserName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);
                    mUserName.setText(names[i]);

                }

            }
        }
    }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Actually it sets them all, but you only see the last one because it loops 'faster than your eyes can see' and it puts the last name in the array in the textview last, so that's the name you see

Comment: What's the expected behavior?

Comment: Woops, that's what I meant.

Comment: I'm searching a table for users who are friends with the current user. I'd like to display those users in a friendslist.

Comment: So, you want a ListView listing all of the names in a list?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html check out listviews and this should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, your code is actually working well:

```
public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response){
            if(users != null){

                String[] names = new String[users.size()];
                for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
                    names[i] = users.get(i).getName();
                    mUserName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);
                    mUserName.setText(names[i]);
                    try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    catch (Exception e){}

                }

            }
        }
    }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: This is only putting the thread to sleep for a little while longer before setting the name. Any other ideas?